# Can I simplify my classes to make them more DRY?

Tags: c#

I have ViewModel classes like these that follow:

```
public class ReferenceDetailsViewModel
{
    public ReferenceDetailsViewModel() {
        this.Timer = new List<long>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Reference.Grid> Grid { get; set; }
    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}

public class ContentDetailsViewModel
{
    public ContentDetailsViewModel() {
        this.Timer = new List<long>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Content.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}
```

They all have in common a Timer field and this is initialized in the constructor.

Is there a way that I could create a baseViewModel and have these inherit the Timer field so as to avoid coding the same thing for each ViewModel that has a timer ?

Comment: This may be more suited to the Code Review stackexchange: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why couldn't you have an `abstract class ViewModel` that your ViewModels inherit from?

Comment: Why do you think you _can't_ just insert a base class? If the code you've posted is the real thing, then you can just chuck the shared functionality into an abstract base class.

Comment: Is that really the only shared code that you have?  If so, trying to change it will probably end up being more work.  If this is just an example and there are either many more classes, or more work that is actually shared, then it could be might be worth the effort.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well. I have a lot of classes that use the timer so I was thinking it would make it easier.

Comment: Did you at least consider creating a base class with the Timer? BTW the constructor of the second class is named incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, code an abstract class and make concrete classes inherit from this.

```
public abstract class BaseDetailsViewModel
{
    protected BaseDetailsViewModel() {
        Timer = new List<long>();
    }
    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it is less confusing if you make constructors on an abstract class `protected` instead of `public`. (Of course `internal` is also possible, but that restricts the access.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can do the following:

```
public abstract class DetailViewModelBase
{
    protected DetailViewModelBase()
    {
        Timer = new List<long>();
    }

    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}

public class ReferenceDetailsViewModel : DetailViewModelBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Reference.Grid> Grid { get; set; }
}


public class ContentDetailViewModel : DetailViewModelBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Content.Grid> Detail { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }

}
```

Use the 'DetailViewModelBase' as base class for you ViewModels containing a 'Timer'.

regards, C#er

Answer (score 1):

If you could extract a common `IGrid` interface from both `Reference.Grid` und `Content.Grid`,  you might get

```
public abstract class GridViewModel<TGrid> where T : IGrid {
    protected GridViewModel() {
        Timer = new List<long>();
    }

    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TGrid> Details { get; set; }
}

public class ReferenceDetailsViewModel : GridViewModel<Reference.Grid> { 

}

public class ContentDetailsViewModel : GridViewModel<Content.Grid> {
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    public List<long> Timer { get; set; }
}
```

I assume that you can live with renaming `ReferenceDetailsViewModel.Grid` to `ReferenceDetailsViewModel.Details`.